# Как грамотно спроектировать игру?

Tags: c++, qt, проектирование, uml

Пишу игру "Жизнь".

Нарисовал такую UML диаграмму классов
[image: Диаграмма классов]

Кратко объясню, что происходит в ней.

1. Есть класс для обработки матрицы `LifeMatrix`. Я могу задавать, получать значения матрицы. матрица - двумерный динамический массив из элементов `bool`.
2. Есть класс `LifeCell`. Это обычная клетка. У неё есть два состояния - мертвая, живая.
3. Класс LifeScene будет отрисовывать клетки `LifeCell` у себя.
4. Класс `Processing` уже будет просчитывать саму игру. В неё я вкидываю размеры поля. Слоты start/stop будут.

Но у меня появилась небольшая проблема. Мне надо как-то отрисовать матрицу в `LifeScene`. Я хотел передавать объект `LifeMatrix`, чтобы я мог её отрисовать по значениях элементов.

У меня есть небольшая идея, как это можно реализовать, но, боюсь, выйдет каша.
Я буду хранить объект `LifeScene` в классе `Processing` и будет в классе LifeScene что-то вроде метода `void LifeScene::redraw(const LifeMatrix &)`, в классе Processing будет метод, возвращающий указатель на сцену `LifeScene* Processing::scene()`. Это также даст возможность задавать размер и сцены и матриц сразу.

Но я боюсь выйдет нечто плохое, поэтому хочу спросить у более опытных людей. Пойдет ли такая стратегия, описанная выше?

Comment: попробуйте описать ответственности для каждого класса. и постарайтесь, что бы у класса была только одна ответсвенность.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я немного погуглил на эту тему. Если правильно понял, то мне надо разбить эти классы на классы поменьше, чтобы была у них одна функция? Это и есть ОДНА ответственность?

Comment: методы может быть больше чем один. А вот responsibility желательно одна.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman ну да, я это имел ввиду. Но это выйдет очень много классов. Или я что-то не понимаю. Есть какой-то хороший материал по SRP(если это оно)?

Comment: не много. Почитайте книги по ОО дизайну. Попробуйте TDD - он помогает сделать хороший дизайн.